# Implement Custom Numpad for EditText

Tags: java, android

I have an application with a numpad (keys 0-9, Ok and Delete) that is always visible on screen.

When the user sets the focus on an `EditText` that has an numeric input method, then the key pressed on the numpad should be applied to the focused `EditText`.

My current approach is to set a `OnFocusChanged` listener on each `EditText` with numeric input method, and then remember the focused control:

```
 EditText txt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        txt1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
          public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
              if(hasFocus)
                  focused = (EditText)v; // focused is a member of the Activity class
          }});
```

Then when a numpad key is pressed the key is applied to the `focused` control.

To me this seems a bit complex, is there an easier way that works automagically (without the focus change listener) on all `EditText` widgets with numeric input method?

Secondly, is there a way to disable the soft keyboard for those `EditText` widgets with numeric input only?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [onKeyDown()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) for your EditText (let's call it numberBox).

The logic is this:

let's say you have all your digit buttons in a collection:

```
private ImageButton []digitButtons = new ImageButton[10];
```

than you set the onClickListeners for each button:

```
private void setClickListenersForDigitButtons() {

    for(int i=0; i < digitButtons.length; i++) {

        int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(getPackageName()+":id/btn_digit_"+i, null, null);

        digitButtons[i] = (ImageButton)findViewById(resId);

        final int keyCode = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0 + i;

        digitButtons[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                keyPressed(keyCode);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And in the keyPressed method:

```
private void keyPressed(int keyCode) {

    KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, keyCode);
    numberBox.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```